# Error: ng:areq Bad Argument payableCtrl is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

### Calling one controller to another controller AngularJS

I have had code that opens a modal and call another controller.

**List Controller**

```
$scope.addPayable = function (booking) {
  var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'views/pages/dashboard/reports/payables.modal.html',
    controller: 'payableCtrl',
    resolve: {
      data: function () {
        return {
          amount: "123"
        };
      }
    }
  });
};
```

This is my second controller

**Payable Controller**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('AniTheme')
  .controller('payableCtrl', ['$scope', '$data', 'uibModalInstance', function ($scope, data, $uibModalInstance) {
    
  }]);
```

console screen of my browser shows me an error.

[image]

The main purpose of doing this, I want to pass some data to the modal screen.

Comment: .controller('payableCtrl', ['$scope', '$data', 'uibModalInstance', function ($scope, $data, $uibModalInstance) {

Comment: applying this code no luck.

Comment: If nothing works out, you store the data in the local storage, and the access it in the other controller. To store data --> localStorage.setItem("fieldName", "value") and to get the data localStorage.getItem("fieldsName");

Comment: @MuhammadUmarKhan post your index html

Comment: that is not the only case I have to use this controller for other purposes as well

Comment: create a demo code so that we can give exact solution rather than guesses

Comment: I just want to open my modal on the same page. when user enter some amount of payable then it will be post to the server

Comment: @ShashankVivek I have provided you a complete code.

Comment: cant see index.html. Can we get the code on plunkr as a demo